# Spring Cloud Stream KStream Consumer Concurrency has no effect?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

My configuration for the consumer is as documented in [Spring cloud stream consumer properties documentation.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.RELEASE/reference/html/_configuration_options.html)

```
spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.SR1
springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
```

I have 4 partitions for `kstream_test` topic and they are filled with messages from producer as seen below:

```
root@kafka:/# kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic kstream_test --time -1
kstream_test:2:222
kstream_test:1:203
kstream_test:3:188
kstream_test:0:278
```

My spring cloud stream kafka binder based configuration is:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input:
  destination: kstream_test
  group: consumer-group-G1_test
  consumer:
    useNativeDecoding: true
    headerMode: raw
    startOffset: latest
    partitioned: true
    concurrency: 3
```

KStream Listener class

```
    @StreamListener
    @SendTo(MessagingStreams.OUTPUT)
    public KStream<?, ?> process(@Input(MessagingStreams.INPUT) KStream<?, ?> kstreams) {
        ......
        log.info("Got a message");
        ......
        return kstreams;
    }
```

My producer sends 100 messages in 1 run. But the logs seems to have only 1 thread `StreamThread-1` handling the messages, though I have concurrency as 3. What might be wrong here ? Is 100 messages not enough to see the concurrency at play ?

```
2018-10-18 11:50:01.923  INFO 10228 --- [-StreamThread-1] c.c.c.s.KStreamHandler     : Got a message
2018-10-18 11:50:01.923  INFO 10228 --- [-StreamThread-1] c.c.c.s.KStreamHandler     : Got a message
2018-10-18 11:50:01.945  INFO 10228 --- [-StreamThread-1] c.c.c.s.KStreamHandler     : Got a message
2018-10-18 11:50:01.956  INFO 10228 --- [-StreamThread-1] c.c.c.s.KStreamHandler     : Got a message
2018-10-18 11:50:01.972  INFO 10228 --- [-StreamThread-1] c.c.c.s.KStreamHandler     : Got a message
```

**UPDATE:**

As per the answer, the below `num.stream.threads` configuration works at the binder level.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration:
 num.stream.threads: 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `num.stream.threads` needs to be set to increase the concurrency...

```
/** {@code num.stream.threads} */
@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public static final String NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG = "num.stream.threads";
private static final String NUM_STREAM_THREADS_DOC = "The number of threads to execute stream processing.";
```

...it defaults to 1.

The binder should really set that based on the `...consumer.concurrency` property; please open a github issue to that effect against [the binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues).

In the meantime, you can just set that property directly in `...consumer.configuration`.

**CORRECTION**

I've just been told that the `...consumer.configuration` is not currently applied to the streams binder either; you would have to set it at the binder level.

Comment: Raised an issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/474

Comment: Hi. Is this resolved ? I am using the same thing and it is not working. Concurrency does not seem to work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77754921/kstreams-is-running-very-slow-in-spring-cloud-stream/77755075?noredirect=1#comment137081119_77755075

Comment: Don’t ask new questions in comments on 5 year old answers. Ask a new question and reference this one if necessary.