# KStreams is running very slow in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have implemented KStreams with SpringCloudStreams in Spring boot.
I am ready from a topic with 20 partitions and writing to a topic with same number of partitions. I have 2 pods running.
The average records being processed is 500k per minute.

I added concurrency of 10 BUT the performance is still the same.
How can I improve performance using concurrency ?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
    function:
      definition: RiskProcessor1
    stream:
      bindings:
        RiskProcessor1-in-0:
          destination: ******
          consumer:
            concurrency: 10
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: kaas-int.nam.nsroot.net:9093
            functions:
              RiskProcessor1:
                applicationId: RiskProcessor1_development
            configuration:
              commit.interval.ms: 1000
              security.protocol: SSL
              default:
                deserialization:
                  exception:
                    handler: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler
              schema:
                registry:
                  url: *****:9081
          default:
            consumer:
              keySerde: ****
              valueSerde: ****
            producer:
              keySerde: ****
              valueSerde: ****
```

Answer (score 0):

A broad outline:

1. Find out where you are hitting the thresholds, memory, cpu or IO. If there is a threshold breach check options to overcome it by upgrading hardware.
2. Find the number of threads can supported by your hardware. There is no point increasing the thread if it is beyond capability of the hardware.

Since you have 20 partitions, you can have at most 20 concurrent consumers possible.

If you use proper serialization like Protocol buffers or Avro, high data traffic will be more performant.

Comment: Thanks much for your response.

I read somewhere KStreams batch is not supported in SpringCloudStream. Is my understanding correct ?

Secondly, when we add concurrency, my assumption was it works as Java multithreading, like the application will spawn multiple threads and will make it faster irrespective of CPU. Isn't it true ? How does it work in synch with hardware ?

Comment: Threshold is just the speed. Memory and CPU I monitored, it is will within the limits. I want to increase speed so I introduced concurrency.

Comment: @HimanshuMahajan Kafka stream API does not support batch, you are right.  Concurrency supposed to increase your performance but it is not irrespective of system resources like CPU.

Comment: @HimanshuMahajan, Have you found where the bottleneck in your application? FWIW, I can't think of any scenario in which the binder in Spring Cloud Stream may cause any issues in this particular case.